Python looks for modules in current working directory on self-hosted azure agent
I have a self-hosted azure windows agent with which I want to run python scripts in a few steps for which I need a couple of libraries. Therefore I added the following tasks to my pipeline.yml
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.12'
        architecture: 'x64'

This installed Python at the location <<agent_home>>\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.7\x64\.
However, it seemed that this didn't include a functioning pip, so I extended it with the following script:
    - script: |
        python -m ensurepip --default-pip
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip

This seemingly worked, but resulted in the following warnings in the log files:
Installing collected packages: pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.12.exe and pip3.exe are installed in '<<agent_home>>\_work\3\s\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Apparently here python is installing and searching for pip and libraries in the current working directory, which is strange to me.
For example I manually tried to execute python.exe -m pip freeze in the location python is installed for this agent, which 'worked', though I'm getting the message "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>".
If I do it one level up and do 'x64\python.exe -m pip freeze' it tells:
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
<<agent_home>>\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.7\x64\python.exe: No module named pip

I was looking around a bit and found for example this two posts here

How can I troubleshoot Python "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"
How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?

and tried to set

PYTHONPATH=<<path_to_python>>/DLLs;<<path_to_python>>/Lib and
PYTHONHOME=<<path_to_python>>

but it didn't help. Changing the PYTHONPATH didn't change anything and after setting PYTHONHOME I get
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000410c (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Can somebody maybe give me a hint, what I have to change in order to get Python properly running here? Thank you.

Have your tried the steps shared in below answer to install pip? Does it work for you? @Christian

You can try the following command to install pip into a specified directory.
python -m ensurepip --root path/of/root/dir --default-pip --upgrade

The argument '--root path/to/root/dir' is used to specified the root directory where pip is installed into. Replace "path/to/root/dir" with an actual path that you want on the agent. For more details, see "ensurepip — Bootstrapping the pip installer".
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Install Python'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.12'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: |
    python -m ensurepip --root path/of/root/dir --default-pip --upgrade
    pip -V
  displayName: 'Install pip'


Since you are using self-hosted Windows agent, you also can following the steps below to install the Python and pip.
Logon your Windows agent machine and do the following things:

Download the installation package of Python version you want. Click the downloaded installation package (.exe) to start the installation.

On the Installation Wizard, ensure you have selected the option 'pip' so that pip also will be installed with Python.


After successfully installing Python, open its installation directory, you can see pip has been installed together.


Go to the installation directory of your self-hosted agent (e.g., E:\VstsAgents\Win11_01) and then go to the subdirectory "_work\_tool", manually create the following directory structure (see the documentation "UsePythonVersion@0"):
path/to/_work/_tool
    Python/
        3.12.7/ <--- The detailed version number of installed Python.
            x64/  <--- The platform (x86 or x64).
            x64.complete  <--- {platform}.complete



Copy all the files and folders from the installation directory of Python into the 'x64' folder created above.


If you want to preinstall multiple Python versions (e.g., 3.12, 3.13, etc..) on the Windows agent machine for use, you can use the same steps like as above to install each version.


When using the self-hosted Windows agent to run pipelines:
Since pip has been installed together with Python, you do not need extra steps to install it when running the pipelines.
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Install Python'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.12'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: pip -V
  displayName: 'Show pip version'


If you want to ensure pip is using a latest of available version, you can use the command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip".
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Install Python'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.12'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip -V
  displayName: 'Upgrade pip'



